# extract from list of elements R with specific length

Tags: r

I have a list of items:
List_item is the following (extract):

```
List_item=c("SA","SB","SC","SC1","SC11","SC12","SC13","SC2","SC21")
```

from which I would like to extract and put in a list "List_2letters" the elements of length 2.
Later on this List_2letters  will use it to do some operations.
I googled a bit but cold not find a solution.

Comment: Using "nchar()" could be your solution

Answer (score 2):

```
List_2letters = List_item[nchar(List_item) == 2]
```